# how to work with mouse and arrow keys on select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use arrow keys in this code if i change option using keys then class should be add into the div and background color should be change as user change the option!

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('option').hover(function() {
      4
      $('#colr').removeAttr('class');
      $('#colr').attr('class', '');
      $('#colr')[0].className = '';
      if ($(this).val() == 'red') {
        $('#colr').addClass('red');
      } else if ($(this).val() == 'green') {
        $('#colr').addClass('green');
      } else if ($(this).val() == 'blue') {
        $('#colr').addClass('blue');
      } else {
        $('#colr').addClass('black');
      }
    });

  });
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:200px;width:200px" id='colr'></div>
<select id="sel">

  <option class="d" value="red">red</option>
  <option value="green" selected="selected">green</option>
  <option class="d" value="blue">blue</option>
  <option class="d" value="black">black</option>

</select>
```

Comment: check keycode and eventlisteners doc https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

Comment: do you want to change the background when you change the selected option using mouse click or updown arrow key?

Comment: no i want to add a class in div and related css of class should be apply as i   change the option using up and down arrow keys- Newinjava

Comment: that's the same. i am talking about the functionality. :) @komal

Answer (score 1):

Try this, first: the code will work `onchange` second you had a unused `4` digit in code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sel').on('change',function() {
      $('#colr').removeAttr('class');
      $('#colr').attr('class', '');
      $('#colr')[0].className = '';
      if ($(this).val() == 'red') {
        $('#colr').addClass('red');
      } else if ($(this).val() == 'green') {
        $('#colr').addClass('green');
      } else if ($(this).val() == 'blue') {
        $('#colr').addClass('blue');
      } else {
        $('#colr').addClass('black');
      }
    });

  });
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:200px;width:200px" id='colr'>Div</div>
<select id="sel">
  <option class="d" value="red">red</option>
  <option value="green" selected="selected">green</option>
  <option class="d" value="blue">blue</option>
  <option class="d" value="black">black</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind an event on the select element as :

javascript :-

```
document.getElementById("id").onchange = function() {//your code that changes the background};
```

link :- https://jsfiddle.net/z7t8m0oy/

jquery :-

```
$("#id").change(function() {//your code that changes the background});
```

link : - https://jsfiddle.net/z7t8m0oy/1/

Answer (score -1):

You need to call a function on change of your list.

```
<select id="sel" onchange="jsFunc()">
    <option class="d" value="red">red</option>
    <option value="green" selected="selected">green</option>
    <option class="d" value="blue">blue</option>
    <option class="d" value="black">black</option>
</select>

<script>
    function jsFunc()
    {
       //do your stuff 
    }
</script>
```